# ASP.NET MVC3 Publish settings in web.config

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config

I have published an ASP.NET MVC3 site.  It runs great.  However, looking back at my web.config file, I was not sure if some of the values I used are correct for publishing versus for developing.  These configurations are in the `<system.web>` section.

```
...
    <system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" executionTimeout="200" maxRequestLength="20000000"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
...
```

I read here ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx ) that using debug=true in compilation will disregard the executionTimeout of 200, and use a default value of 110.  This seems to be the case, and the site is setup to allow very large amounts of files to be uploaded all at once.  However, with only 110 seconds, not much can be uploaded.

My question is this: Is the correct setting to publish a live site for debug "false"?  In addition, is requestValidationMode="2.0" still safe to use considering asp.net is now on version 4 (soon to be 4.5)?

Comment: When debug is true, there is NO execution timeout. You should always set debug to false when publishing and explicitly set the executionTimeout if you need longer than the default.

Comment: Yes, I realized that the upload is actually taking place, but there is a bottleneck somewhere else.  I am trying to upload 9MB of pictures at once, but it will not take them once uploaded.  If I do them separately it works, but not all at once.

Comment: Are you on IIS 7+? If so, make sure the request filtering maxAllowedContentLength is not configured to low. I think default for that is pretty large....

Comment: @dotjoe I do not think this is the case, I can upload 3 images totaling 15 MB, but cannot upload 4 images totaling 400kb.

Comment: Also, be aware that maxRequestLength is in kb (20000000kb ~ 19g) while maxAllowedContentLength is in bytes.

Comment: Is maxAllowedContentLength part of web.config as well?

Comment: Yep in iis 7 specific system.webServer... http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Validationmode 2.0 is not the framework version and can stay like that.

Put debug=false and you are fine.

Answer (score 2):

requestValidationMode... As far as I'm aware, this *has* to be set to 2.0 if you want to allow special characters (<, >, % etc.) in request data to pass ASP.NET's request validation at all. requestValidationMode="2.0" means "only enforce validation on pages (i.e. .aspx), rather than on *every* request (as was introduced in 4.0). That allows ASP.NET MVC to take over the validation - and hence also lets you turn it off for specific requests.

Is it safe? It is, if you've made sure that any actions or controllers that have `[ValidateInput(false)]` applied or models with `[AllowHtml]` have been properly secured against attacks. Imran Baloch has a full explanation [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/02/19/understanding-request-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx).

And yes, debug should be "false" for several reasons, including performance and memory usage. Also, debug="true" changes the default cache policy for static files to never cache the files in the browser, meaning tons of redundant requests for scripts, CSS etc.

As for the image upload, other than the suggestions given, check in Event Viewer that it's not really the application pool recycling for one reason or other, rather than an execution timeout.